# java Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am new to android studio and I would like to use jackson in an android-studio project.
I found two .jar files who seems to make what I am looking for ("jackson-core-asl-1.8.5" and "jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5"). I have included the dependencies in the app build.graddle like this :

```
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.8.5'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.8.5'
```

When I simply build the project it works, but when I run it on the android vm the build fail.

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE
>       File1: C:\Users\HAL9000\AndroidStudioProjects\EpiAndroid\EpiAndroid\app\libs\jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\HAL9000\AndroidStudioProjects\EpiAndroid\EpiAndroid\app\libs\jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5.jar
>       File3: C:\Users\HAL9000.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.8.5\713a5564acb9a5467521bbb53221ab8e1fe65039\jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar
>       File4: C:\Users\HAL9000.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.8.5\56439095aa051521c5abb330235820c66886b5e5\jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5.jar

Then I tried to add :

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
```

in the app build.graddle file but it doesn't work too.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by removing the two .jar in /libs, removing my packagingOptions and write this instead :

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

And finally i use this for the dependencies instead:

```
    compile (
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.4.1'],
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.4.1']
)
```

I hope it will help someone in the future.